# Client Certificate not matching during mutual TLS 1.2 handshake

Tags: wcf, tls1.2, client-certificates

I am sending a request from a .NET WCF client to a Service via mutual TLS 1.2 connection.

On the client, I created a new certificate with my own root CA. I loaded this certificate into client's certificate store. The same certificate file has been copied to the server and loaded into trust store so the service could pick it up.

In the code I am creating **WSHttpBinding** with `SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential` and set `ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate`.

Now I am debugging the client and at the same time watching TLS 1.2 packet exchange using *Wireshark*. I can see client app finding my certificate in the store and assigning it to `ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.Certificate` property on the proxy.

But request attempt fails with message

> "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

*Wireshark* shows that TLS 1.2 handshake message exchange continues up to the point where service sends *Certificate Request* with *Distinguished Names* matching exactly my client certificate.

[image]

But unfortunately client responds back with **empty certificate list**! Service terminates the handshake after that, of course.

This is my client certificate:

[image]

[image]

This is Certificate Request from service:
[image]

This is client response:
[image]

Client app is in possession of this certificate, so why is it not returning this certificate upon server's Certificate Request?

UPDATE:

A couple of days after posting my question I came across this earlier [question and solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46559467/503-error-consuming-thirdy-part-soap-webservice-using-tls-1-2-and-client-certifi?rq=1). I obviously had the same issue and my certificate in local certificate store did not have private key. So I followed the instruction to create .pfx, as advised, and now both client and server have another certificate with private key in respective local stores. Unfortunately, the issue is not resolved and symptoms are still the same.

Comment: Hi, May I know how is the issue going on now?

Comment: Hi @TheobaldDu, this is still unresolved.

Answer (score 0):

Use [X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential.SetCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.security.x509certificateinitiatorclientcredential.setcertificate?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0) Method to specify the certificate used by the client. Enter the correct parameter value like below:

```
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySubjectName, "alice");
```